# Could we access to the Qt creator internal parser from a plugin?

Tags: parsing, plugins, abstract-syntax-tree, qt-creator

I would like to make a plugin for Qt Creator, and I want access to the parsing files (AST) in Qt Creator. For example if you right click on a variable, retrieve its type.

I just looked at the doc and I have not found something very significant. And I fear myself having to parse the page.

Anyone have tried it and succeeded? :p

Answer (score 2):

I recommend checking the cppquickfix.cpp file in src/plugins/cppeditor for examples on how to use the C++ engine build into Qt Creator.

That part is definitely accessible to all plugins and even pretty easy to integrate into other applications.

Unfortunately documentation is a bit sparse and the code is pretty complex (mostly since C++ is such a complex language:-). The best place to get help with it is probably either the Qt creator mailing list or the irc channel. Contact information is available [here](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools/).